# Domain stays a cube when baking?

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, fluid-simulation

Whenever I bake my domain, it stays a cube. It does work when the fluid object is outside of a hollow obstacle I've placed it in.

[image: Shot of the model that the fluid is contained within]

I've recalculated the normals, and tried resizing the domain, but nothing really seems to work. Blend file is below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate the normals on all the meshes. Remember to go to edit mode and select all faces. Then go to Your fluid settings on the glass and choose "volume" instead of "both" under volumen initialization:[image]

I have added the fixed file below:-)

[image]